# How do I make Laravel Elixir merge my files rather than overwrite them?

Tags: css, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

There are two stylesheets within my application named `Main.scss` and `Reset.css`. I try to compile the Sass, then merge it with the other stylesheet (`Reset.css`) but I end up missing the styles from `Main.scss`. It was working perfectly well until I decided to add `Reset.css`.

Here's my `gulpfile`:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var assetsDir = 'public/Assets/Stylesheets/';
elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.sass('Main.scss', assetsDir + 'Main.css')
    .styles('Reset.css', assetsDir + 'Main.css')
    .version('Assets/Stylesheets/Main.css');
});
```

How can I make `Reset.css` simply merge into the same file as `Main.css` without overwriting the content from the `.sass` call?

Here's the log from calling `gulp`, also:

```
[21:24:18] Using gulpfile ~/Code/gulpfile.js
[21:24:18] Starting 'default'...
[21:24:18] Starting 'sass'...

Fetching Sass Source Files...
   - resources/assets/sass/Main.scss


Saving To...
   - public/Assets/Stylesheets/Main.css

[21:24:20] Finished 'default' after 1.87 s
[21:24:20] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Sass Compiled!
[21:24:20] Finished 'sass' after 1.98 s
[21:24:20] Starting 'styles'...

Fetching Styles Source Files...
   - resources/assets/css/Reset.css


Saving To...
   - public/Assets/Stylesheets/Main.css

[21:24:20] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Stylesheets Merged!
[21:24:20] Finished 'styles' after 41 ms
[21:24:20] Starting 'version'...

Fetching Version Source Files...
   - public/Assets/Stylesheets/Main.css


Saving To...
   - public/build

[21:24:20] Finished 'version' after 45 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating you Main.css with sass, but then immediately overwriting it with Reset.css. The styles method is there to concatenate different stylesheets, which you can specify as an array as the first argument.

So you would say

```
.styles(['Reset.css', 'Main.css'], assetsDir + 'Main.css')
```

In that case though, it will look for Main.css in the resources directory. You can overwrite were the .mix function saves your Main.css by giving a second argument.

So for example

```
mix.sass('Main.scss', 'resources/assets/css/Main.css')
   .style(['Main.css','Reset.css'], assetsDir + 'all.css']
```

Comment: Great! I've managed to merge `Main.css` and `Reset.css`, although I wanted `Reset.css` to be first, so I ended up with this code:    

`elixir(function(mix) {
      mix.sass('Main.scss', 'resources/assets/css/Main.css')
        .styles([
          'Reset.css',
          'Main.css'
        ], cssDir + 'Main.css');
    });`